# In rails, what is the equivalent of asp.net's App_Code folder?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

In rails, what is the equivalent of asp.net's App_Code folder?

Eg, where do you put your various utility classes for your complicated business logic that you don't want to shove in your controllers or helpers?

Answer (score 2):

That would be the `lib` directory.

Answer (score 1):

To be clear, complicated business logic goes into your model. Stick with the convention of thick models, skinny controllers.

If you have **view** related helper methods these go into your helpers. Other miscellaneous  stuff can be put in your `lib` directory as @Jakub said.